# How to check for the presence of a location in a sentence in R?

Tags: r

I am very new to R.

I want to check a particular sentence has a location name or not. For example

`sentence <- " I am travelling to Tulsa"`.

How should i write a code so that the program can understand that the sentence contains a world called "Tulsa"  and which is a location. Should i build a manual dictionary containing the required locations?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `R` has not implemented a list of Towns or other locations as this is very specific. Thus I would search for a list in the web. If you have such a list, you can work e.g. with

```
grep("Tulsa", sentence, fixed = T) # [1] 1
grep("Tulsaa", sentence, fixed = T) # integer(0)
```

You can then work with a list, but things might get demanding:

```
sentences <- c("I am travelling to Tulsa", "I am travelling to Washington and York", 
               "I am travelling to Tulsa and New York")
cities <- c("Tulsa", "New York", "York")
grep(cities[1], sentences, fixed = T) # [1] 1 3
grep(cities[2], sentences, fixed = T) # [1] 3
grep(cities[3], sentences, fixed = T) # [1] 2 3
```

I hope that helps. Speed optimzation will be a different topic...

Comment: thanks for the response. It worked. Is it possible to make a list of locations in a dicitonary kind of list and refer the same (instead of hard coding as "Tulsa". Can you help if possible.

Comment: @SijoK See my edit.

Comment: thankyou very much for he help